# Interact with HTML string as if it were document?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to be able to interact with an HTML string as if it was `document`. Something like:

```js
    var html_string = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Page Title</title></head><body><h1 id="id1" class="test test2">This is a Heading</h1><p id="id2" class="test">This is a paragraph.</p></body></html>'

console.log(html_string.getElementById('id1'));
console.log(html_string.getElementsByClassName('test'));
console.log(html_string.querySelector('.test.test2'));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can parse an HTML string with the native DOMParser:

```js
var html_string = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Page Title</title></head><body><h1 id="id1" class="test test2">This is a Heading</h1><p id="id2" class="test">This is a paragraph.</p></body></html>'

var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html_string,"text/html")
                            
console.log(doc.getElementById('id1').innerHTML );
console.log(doc.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].innerHTML  );
console.log(doc.querySelector('.test.test2').innerHTML );
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I will upvote tomorrow (reached my limit)

Comment: But if I were you ...I would have used jquery & made code even simpler